# Which form to run?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to build a page with multiple similar forms on one page. Each form is very simple, it provides an integer input and a submit button. Each form corresponds to a counter, and the counter is supposed to be increased when the form is submitted.

```
incrementCounterForm :: Entity Counter -> Form (CounterId, Int)
incrementCounterForm (Entity i _) = renderBoostrap3 BootstrapInlineForm
                                      $ (,) 
                                        <$> pure i 
                                        <*> areq intField "value" Nothing
```

In my GET handler I do

```
counters <- runDB $ selectList [] [] -- Get all the current counters
forms <- mapM (generateFormPost . incrementCounterForm) counters -- Generate the forms
```

Then in my hamlet file I iterate over the forms and render them all individually (they all go to the same handler).

My question relates to the POST handler. How do I do the runFormPost?

```
((result,_),_) <- runFormPost $ incrementCounterForm undefined
```

What should `undefined` be here? I want to get the counter from the form, not have to provide one.

EDIT: I lied about providing an arbitrary counter working

<s>If I do provide an arbitrary `Entity Counter` it seems to work (the provided counter is not used in the result). Yet, I can't leave it as `undefined` because runFormPost seems to evaluate it.</s>

Comment: Am I under the false impression that `pure` will embed a hidden input field?

Comment: Indeed, changing it from `pure` to `areq hiddenField "" (Just i)` makes it work if I provide an arbitrary `Entity Counter` field. Still doesn't work with undefined.

Comment: One approach you could take is to move the counter ID into the URL. I'm not sure what your current URL structure looks like, but if you could POST to /counters/1/increment or whatever, you wouldn't need to store the counter ID in a hidden field.

Comment: I had thought of that, and it is what I am currently doing. I just thought that this method should work as well, and wanted to know why it doesn't. I was hoping Haskells laziness would have allowed me to use `undefined` when reading forms back in.

Comment: Cool, I would probably avoid `undefined`. For doing it with hidden fields, I just posted an answer that would work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'd probably advise moving your counter ID into the URL, so you're doing something like POSTing to /counters/1/increment or something. Feels slightly off to have the ID in a hidden field.

However, if you did want to keep it in a hidden field, you can have the form take a `Maybe (Entity Counter)` as an argument. What you'll do is when the user GETs the page and you're generating the form, you'll pass in a `(Just entity)` as the argument which you'll use to populate the hidden field. When the user POSTs to you and you run the form, you'll provide no default value (because you want the value that was stored in the hidden field).

Here's an example of what that would look like:

```
data MyForm = MyForm
    { increment :: Integer
    , counterId :: CounterId
    }
  deriving Show

myForm :: Maybe (Entity Counter) -> AForm Handler MyForm
myForm maybeEntity = MyForm
        <$> areq intField "How much to increment?" Nothing
        <*> areq hiddenField "" (entityKey <$> maybeEntity)
```

When generating the form, provide a value for the hidden field:

```
(widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost $ renderBootstrap (myForm (Just someEntity))
```

When running the form, don't provide a default value; the hidden field should have the data already:

```
((res, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost $ renderBootstrap (myForm Nothing)
```